# Getting SQLITE ERROR incomplete input error. What's wrong?

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, sql-insert, node-sqlite3

While running this SQLITE statement, I am getting error:  incomplete input

```
return db.run(
  `INSERT INTO articles(article_id, title, author, article) VALUES `+"('"+article_id+"', '"+data.title+"', '"+data.author+"', '"+data.article+"')",
  (err) => callback(err, article_id));
```

What's wrong in it? I have logged all the data inputs, but they are having correct values in the query(i.e. no values missing). Is it due to wrong syntax? Please help.

Comment: What's wrong?  You are munging the query string with literal values.  You need to learn to use parameters.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote on this? How is this a bad question? I have a similar problem but don't dare to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that one of your variables contains a character that clashes with the query string - such as a single quote for example.

Don't mungle variables in your query string. This is both unsafe (it opens up your code to SQL injection), inefficient (the database can't recognize that you are running the same query), and error-prone.

Instead, use a parameterized query:

```
return db.run(
    "INSERT INTO articles(article_id, title, author, article) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    [ article_id, data.title, data.author, data.article ],
    (err) => callback(err, article_id)
);
```

Comment: I was using this parameterized code earlier, but still it was not working. I just dropped my table and it worked normally.